# How to wait for page to load in C# web browser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a sequence of code that I want to run.

1. Visit website
2. Clear cookies
3. Open login page
4. login
5. submit form

Problem is after running #3, the #4 code starts running before waiting for the login page to load.

I tried using `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler`, but it shows error everytime.

Below is my code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(ClearCookies);
        webBrowser.Navigate("https://www.example.com/");
    }


    void ClearCookies(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(Login1);
        webBrowser.Navigate("javascript:void((function(){var a,b,c,e,f;f=0;a=document.cookie.split('; ');for(e=0;e<a.length&&a[e];e++){f++;for(b='.'+location.host;b;b=b.replace(/^(?:%5C.|[^%5C.]+)/,'')){for(c=location.pathname;c;c=c.replace(/.$/,'')){document.cookie=(a[e]+'; domain='+b+'; path='+c+'; expires='+new Date((new Date()).getTime()-1e11).toGMTString());}}}})())");
    }

    void LoginPage(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(Login1);
        webBrowser.Navigate("https://example.com/Login/");

    }

    void Login(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(Login2);
        webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("Email").InnerText = "email@gmail.com";

        HtmlElementCollection elc = this.webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)
        {
            if (el.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit"))
            {
                el.InvokeMember("Click");
            }
        }
    }




    void form(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(Nothing);
        webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("name").InnerText = "test";
        HtmlElementCollection elc2 = this.webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement el in elc2)
        {
            if (el.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit"))
            {
                el.InvokeMember("Click");
            }
        }
    }

    void Nothing(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Also I get another error:

> this.mainWbrowser.DocumentTitle   error CS1061: 'Form1' does not contain a definition for 'mainWbrowser' and no extension method 'mainWbrowser' accepting a first argument of type 'Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You already have it in the code, the event DocumentCompleted. Just put your code in that handler.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Put which code in which handler? I already have the code inside the eventhandler.

Comment: You do **not** have the code in your handler, you have it in your `form` constructor. Take the `webBrowser.Document.GetElementById...` stuff out of your  constructor and put it in your `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler`, which you have called `Nothing` for some inexplicable reason.

Comment: @DourHighArch Could you provide a answer with code please? I do not understand what you mean. I've called `Nothing` after form submit is done, and there's no need to do anything more after documentcomplete.